# Magento 2 /rest/V1/categories/ get Include in menu and Url key

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How to add the below attributes in **"/V1/categories/"** api response

```
include_in_menu

url_key
```

[image]

thanks

Comment: Raghu, you cannot get current frontend  menu at api.

Comment: no actually i need https://prnt.sc/hjf7ff url_key and iclude_in_menu here

Comment: please check the the attributes scope in global level or store level?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get full response from category using API - Including **include_in_menu and url_key with product count as well**. You need to pass **category id** with your **URL**

**Below is the example url and its structure which i have done .**

**URL :** **http://10.0.0.55/rest/V1/categories/3**

**Response :**

```
{
"id": 3,
"parent_id": 1,
"name": "Sale",
"is_active": true,
"position": 2,
"level": 1,
"children": "",
"created_at": "2017-11-17 07:41:27",
"updated_at": "2017-11-17 07:41:27",
"path": "1/3",
"available_sort_by": [],
"include_in_menu": true,
"custom_attributes": [
    {
        "attribute_code": "path",
        "value": "1/3"
    },
    {
        "attribute_code": "children_count",
        "value": "0"
    },
    {
        "attribute_code": "url_key",
        "value": "sale"
    }
]
```

}